# Form Switch can change UI but doesn't update the state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, frontend

**Description**

I have a table with many switches.

[image]

when I clicked that switch. The switch is working perfectly, I can turn it on/off with it.
but the problem is that I can't change the initial value from the state. Even if I turn the switch off, it still logs value like this :

[image]

I set the initial state of checked to true, but the UI also shows like this :

[image]

I've tried changing the code of the handler, state of value, etc. But I don't have any idea.

**Expected Output**

The expected output is that when I click on the second row or apply for multiple role permissions, the number of objects placed into an array should increase. Example:

```
[
    {
      add: true,
      modify: false,
      delete: true,
      view: false,
      export: true,
      permission: "user",
    },
    {
      add: true,
      modify: false,
      delete: true,
      view: false,
      export: true,
      permission: "user_group",
    },
]
```

**Code**

Here's the codesandbox demo :

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-checkbox-40tm39?file=/src/App.js

App.js (parent)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TableRole from "./TableRole";
import { Card, Button, Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Tambah Group Role";
  }, []);

  // state for input form group and switches
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    groupId: "",
    groupName: "",
    groupDesc: ""
  });

  const initialValues = [
    {
      id: 1,
      add: true,
      modify: true,
      delete: true,
      view: true,
      export: true,
      permission: "user"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      add: true,
      modify: true,
      delete: true,
      view: true,
      export: true,
      permission: "user_group"
    }
  ];

  const [checkedValues, setCheckedValues] = useState(initialValues);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(checkedValues);
  }, [checkedValues]);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue({
      ...value,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  const onCheckboxChange = (event, permission, index) => {
    setCheckedValues((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      newState[index] = {
        ...newState[index],
        [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
      };
      return newState;
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(checkedValues);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card>
                <Card.Title>
                  <p className="text-uppercase base-lg text-semi-bold">
                    Informasi Grup Akun
                  </p>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Body></Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card className="border-0 mt-5">
                <Card.Title>
                  <p className="text-uppercase base-lg text-semi-bold mt-2 mx-2">
                    Kontrol Akses
                  </p>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Body>
                  <TableRole
                    checkedValues={checkedValues}
                    onChange={onCheckboxChange}
                  />
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <Button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

TableRole (child)

```
import React from "react";
import { Table, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function TableRole({ checkedValues, onChange }) {
  const tableHeader = [
    "No",
    "Menu",
    "Sub Menu",
    "Lihat",
    "Tambah",
    "Ubah",
    "Hapus",
    "Export"
  ];

  const tableData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      menu: "Dashboard",
      submenu: ["-"]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      menu: "Konfigurasi/Pengaturan",
      submenu: [
        {
          name: "Akun Pengguna",
          permission: "user",
          permissionIndex: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Grup",
          permission: "user_group",
          permissionIndex: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Table className="table-responsive">
      <thead
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECEFF1" }}
        className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold"
      >
        <tr>
          {tableHeader.map((header, index) => (
            <th
              key={index}
              className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold text-center"
              style={{ padding: "0.75rem" }}
            >
              {header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="text-center">
        {tableData.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <React.Fragment key={rowIndex}>
            <RoleRow
              index={rowIndex + 1}
              menu={row.menu}
              submenu={row.submenu}
              checked={checkedValues}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

const RoleRow = ({ index, menu, submenu, checked, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <tr>
        <td rowSpan={submenu.length + 1}>{index}</td>
        <td rowSpan={submenu.length + 1}>{menu}</td>
      </tr>
      {submenu.map((subMenuItem, subMenuItemIndex) => (
        <tr key={`${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}-${subMenuItem.permission}`}>
          <td>{subMenuItem.name}</td>
          <PermissionCheckbox checked={checked} onChange={(e) => onChange} />
        </tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const PermissionCheckbox = ({ index, subMenuItemIndex, checked, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <td>
        <Form.Check
          id={`lihat-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
          type="switch"
          name="view"
          defaultChecked={checked.view}
          value={checked.view}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <Form.Check
          id={`tambah-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
          type="switch"
          name="add"
          defaultChecked={checked.add}
          value={checked.add}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <Form.Check
          id={`ubah-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
          type="switch"
          name="modify"
          defaultChecked={checked.modify}
          value={checked.modify}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <Form.Check
          id={`hapus-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
          type="switch"
          name="delete"
          defaultChecked={checked.delete}
          value={checked.delete}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <Form.Check
          id={`export-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
          type="switch"
          name="export"
          defaultChecked={checked.export}
          value={checked.export}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </td>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Question**

1. How to set defaultValues based on state?
2. How to update the state correctly?

any help will be appreciated, thankyou

Comment: In my opion, you should combine `tableData` into `checkedValues` and generate `RoleRow` by `checkedValues` single, then bind data, the problem is you manage sub component with two data source, one from parent, the other one is inside it.

Comment: would you please tell me how , sir ?

Comment: Please see [App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-farrell-r5remz?file=/src/App.js) and [TableRole.jsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-farrell-r5remz?file=/src/TableRole.jsx) for changes.

Comment: You are an expert in this field! I am truly impressed with the solution you provided. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: sir, how can i get only the submenu , for each object state ? . example :      console.log(checkedValues[1].submenu);
Is there a way to collect the submenu details for object index number one if the state object increases in value?

Comment: If you want get submenu data of id '2-1',try `const result = checkedValues.find(menu=>menu.id === '2-1'.split('-')[0]).submenu` 
```